# A geometry problem of cyclic quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry

In the  given figure $A$ is the cyclic quadrilateral.I would like to find the relation between angle $\alpha$ and $\angle GHF$. can someone help me please. Thanks.

[image: Cyclic quadrilateral]

Comment: Is the inscribed quadrilateral a trapezium?

Comment: @Bernard no, it is arbitrary quadrilateral with one side as the diameter.

Comment: Did you use GeoGebra for drawing or something?

Comment: @Babaxor Yes.  I got the required relation too. Thanks everyone.

Comment: If there is no cyclic quadrilateral rather than $GDCF$ then $\alpha$ and $\angle GHF$ will be independent angles.

Comment: @HoseynHeydari: $G$ and $F$ have to be antipodal points, hence *there is* a relation between $\widehat{FHG}$ and $\alpha$, namely $\widehat{FHG}=\frac{\pi-\alpha}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $G$ and $F$ are antipodal points, we have $FD\perp GH$ and $GC\perp FH$.

It follows that $\widehat{FHG}$ is the complementary angle of $\widehat{CGH}=\widehat{CGD}=\frac{1}{2}\widehat{CAD}$, so:

$$ \widehat{FHG} = \frac{\pi-\alpha}{2}.$$